# server side of Fetch API request doesn't receive data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am sending data with a `POST` request via Fetch, but it appears as if the data is not received on the server side. You will find what happens after the code.

CLIENT POST REQUEST

```PHP
const formMobile = document.getElementById('quoteMobile');
if (formMobile) {
    formMobile.addEventListener('submit', function(e){  
      e.preventDefault()

console.log("submit fired");
console.log(            
                document.getElementById('fromDate').value +
                document.getElementById('toDate').value +
                 document.querySelector('input[name="unit"]:checked').value + 
                 document.getElementById("total").value +
                document.getElementById("lan").value
);
    
     fetch('/api/apicreatebooking.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({        
                fromDate: document.getElementById('fromDate').value,
                toDate: document.getElementById('toDate').value,
                apptmnt: document.querySelector('input[name="unit"]:checked').value,
                total: document.getElementById("total").value,
                lan: document.getElementById("lan").value
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          }
      })
    .then(function(response){ 
        return response.json()})
    .then(function(data){
console.log(data)
        body=document.getElementById("bodyDiv")
        messages=document.getElementById("messagesDiv");
        if (data.success) {
            bookingCode = data.bookingCode;
            phpFile = 'mbooking_form_content2.php'
            $('#bodyDiv').load('/presentation/' + phpFile + '?bookingCode=' + bookingCode);
        } else {
            messages.innerHTML = data.message;
        } 
    }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); 
    });
    
}
```

SERVER SIDE

```js
<?php
$a="a>";
if (isset($_POST['fromDate'])) {$a += $_POST['fromDate'];}
if (isset($_POST['toDate'])) {$a += $_POST['toDate'];}
if (isset($_POST['apptmnt'])) {$a += $_POST['apptmnt'];}
if (isset($_POST['total'])) {$a += $_POST['total'];}
if (isset($_POST['lan'])) {$a += $_POST['lan'];}
$result = array(
    "success" => true,
    "message" => $a,
    "bookingCode" => '1234567'
);

$output = json_encode($result);
echo $output;
```

From the 2nd client side `console.log`, I see that all data is present. The server side also returns the `$result` array, however, it looks like this (client side `console.log`: `{success: true, message: "a>", bookingCode: "1234567"}`. So none of the transmitted data has been received - or at least I cannot receive it with `$_POST`.

For some strange reason I have found very little documentation of the server side of the Fetch API, but my understanding is it works like any POST request (if using POST for the request). I also found one answer where someone removed the content-type from the success and became lucky, didn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch request is sending json to the server, the server is not expecting json, its expecting form data.
You can use a URLSearchParams object to send that type of data to your server.

```
 fetch('/api/apicreatebooking.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new URLSearchParams ({        
            fromDate: document.getElementById('fromDate').value,
            toDate: document.getElementById('toDate').value,
            apptmnt: document.querySelector('input[name="unit"]:checked').value,
            total: document.getElementById("total").value,
            lan: document.getElementById("lan").value
      })
  })
```

---

If you actually want to send JSON from the client side you have to change the way you read it on the server. The data is not stored in $_POST, you have to read it from stdin.

```
<?php
$a="a>";
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
if (isset($data['fromDate'])) {$a += $data['fromDate'];}
if (isset($data['toDate'])) {$a += $data['toDate'];}
if (isset($data['apptmnt'])) {$a += $data['apptmnt'];}
if (isset($data['total'])) {$a += $data['total'];}
if (isset($data['lan'])) {$a += $data['lan'];}
$result = array(
    "success" => true,
    "message" => $a,
    "bookingCode" => '1234567'
);

$output = json_encode($result);
echo $output;
```

Comment: This sounds very convincing. I just implemented it but yet no change (done both sides). Tomorrow I will look into this in more detail to get it work with this new information

Comment: Did you try each side individually? Don't do both only do one

Comment: Sorry was in a rush yesterday and did not read carefully enough. In THEORY it works great now, in PRACTICE this is totally weird: `$a=print_r($data,true);` provides me `"stdClass Object(    [fromDate] => 2022-07-09 [toDate] => 2022-07-16 ...` as response, however, as soon as I use `if (isset($data['toDate']))` or `$a += $data['apptmnt'];` (any value), I receive `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:8888/api/apibooking.php` and `Error: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.` in `.catch(error => ...`

Comment: I found the issue: It has to be `$data = json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score 0):

There is a little issue with 2nd code snippet above from Musa.

It has to be `$data = json_decode($json, true);`