# cannot read php map coming from POST request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dictionary, post

Due to some other issues I have replaced a "standard" POST request with JSON based POST request via Fetch API. After some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091714/server-side-of-fetch-api-request-doesnt-receive-data/73091835#73091835) I got the server side running. However, as soon as I read an element from my results array, I receive an error.

POST REQUEST

```js
fetch('/api/apicreatebooking.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({        
                'fromDate': document.getElementById('fromDate').value,
                'toDate': document.getElementById('toDate').value,
                'apptmnt': document.querySelector('input[name="unit"]:checked').value,
                'total': document.getElementById("total").value,
                'lan': document.getElementById("lan").value
          })
})
.then(function(response){ 
        return response.json()})
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

SERVER SIDE PHP FOR POST REQUEST

```php
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json);
$a="a>";

//if (isset($data['total'])) {$a += $data['total'];}

$a=print_r($data,true);
$result = array(
    "success" => true,
    "message" => $a,
    "bookingCode" => '1234567'
);

$output = json_encode($result);
echo $output;
```

The code as stated above returns in the console

`Object`

`bookingCode: "1234567"`

`message: "stdClass Object↵(↵    [fromDate] => 2022-07-02↵    [toDate] => 2022-07-09↵    [apptmnt] => 2↵    [total] => 11340 €↵    [lan] => DE↵)↵"`

`success: true`

However, as soon as I swap the comment on the server side (`if (isset...`) to be code
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:8888/api/apibooking.php and Error: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.`

Comment: what is $a="a>"?

Comment: In case of 500 error you have to look into php error log for the error message.

Comment: @YourCommonSense $a="a>" is the variable that I return with the request. And I profile this with something, so that something is returned, when the data I add to $a is empty. Not sure, whether you closed the question - however, I think with POST request landing page I hardly get any PHP errors displayed since the page doesn't output anything to the client. I didn't even get the console.log to work on this landing page

Comment: Nobody said console.log. You need the error log **on the server.** You are getting 500 error from the server, and, therefore, have to look into the error logs on the server.

Comment: Does it make any sense to add some number to a value like `a>`? What result you expect?

Comment: if it is int, maybe not. Anyhow, I now managed to find the error log file (at a different spot than  definied in php.ini) and I found the issue. Now I even know hoe to check this log :)